# Listen to UIkit modal events in Angular 4 components

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, getuikit

How can I listen to events emitted from UIkit's [Modal](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#events) dialog in my Angular component?

I want to run some code when the modal is closed and have added `(hidden)="onModalHidden()"` on the modal div but the method is never being called.

**HTML Template**

```html
<div id="modal-user-data" uk-modal (hidden)="onModalHidden()">
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body uk-overflow-auto">
    <h4 class="uk-modal-title uk-heading-divider">Header</h4>
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p class="uk-text-right">
      <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" type="button">close</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```js
onModalHidden() {
  console.log('Never called...');
}
```

I'm using Angular 4.4.5 and UIkit 3.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To sheed some light yes, you can:

```
import * as uikit from 'uikit';
```

And then:

```
deleteUser(): void {
    uikit.modal.alert('Deleting user');
}
```

Thanks to danca

Answer (score 1):

I've never used them together, but according to the documentation, you can use UIkit with React. Only remember to use data-uk attributes instead of uk-only attributes.

Also UIkit is written in a way that js components are written these days. You can try to import them with `import * from 'uikit'` and see what happens. I would go this way, and if it is not enough - focus on instating component with javascript, not by tag properties.